# Plotting points in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to plot a few points on the following picture in Mathematica:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
   {{u, v, (Cos[u] + Cos[v])/3}, {u, -1, (Cos[u] + Cos[0])/3}, 
   {5, v, (Cos[4] + Cos[v])/3}}, {u, -4, 4}, {v, 0, 8}, Axes -> False, 
 Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {8, 8, 1.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(they should just look like dots on the surface)

What I was trying to do is enter the coordinates of the points manually on another graph using ListPointPlot3D, and then combine them using Show. But for some reason that isn't working. Suggestions?

Also, I would like to add small vectors tangent to the surface in the x directions for the points I have plotted, but I have no idea on how to do that, so suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow. Remember to accept the answer that best answers your question, by clicking on the checkmark next to that answer. Once you have a bit more reputation, you can do things like upvote good answers (and questions), and comment on posts that are not your own. You might also be interested to check out the proposal for a dedicated Mathematica users site in the StackExchange network: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15787/mathematica

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps this will help you get started on a solution.  It plots 3 random points on the surface. You can change the number of points by setting `nPoints`.  I don't know how to plot  tangents along x. But when you figure that out you can use `Arrow`s, as suggested by @Verbeia.

```
nPoints = 3;
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{
       {u, v, (Cos[u] + Cos[v])/3}, 
       {u, -1, (Cos[u] + Cos[0])/3}, {5,  v, (Cos[4] + Cos[v])/3}}, 
       {u, -4, 4}, {v, 0, 8}, Axes -> False, 
       Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {8, 8, 1.5},
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]]],

     Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.025], 
         Point[Table[{u1 = RandomReal[{-3, 3}], v1 = RandomReal[{1, 7}], 
         (Cos[u1] + Cos[v1])/3}, {nPoints}]]}]]
```

[image: points on surface]

### Edit

The following dynamic variation makes use of @belisarius 's contribution:

```
Manipulate[
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{{u, v, (Cos[u] + Cos[v])/3} },
  {u, -4, 4}, {v, 0, 8}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
  BoxRatios -> {8, 8, 1.5},
  Mesh -> None,
  ImageSize -> {400, 300},
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 8}},
  PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1.4}, {0, 0}},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]]],
Graphics3D[({Red, PointSize[.025], 
  Point@f[pt[[1, 1]], pt[[1, 2]]], Black, 
  Arrow[{f[pt[[1, 1]], pt[[1, 2]]], 
  f[pt[[1, 1]], pt[[1, 2]]] + D[f[t, pt[[1, 2]]], t] /. 
   t -> pt[[1, 1]]}]}]],
Grid[{{
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
  Dynamic[Graphics[{},
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 8}},
   Frame -> True,
   ImageSize -> 160,
   FrameTicks -> {Range[-4, 4], Range[0, 8], None, None},
   FrameLabel -> {"u", "v"},
   GridLines -> {Range[-4, 4], Range[0, 8]},
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray]]],
   {{-4, 0}, {4, 8}}]}}],
  {{pt, {{1, 2}}}, ControlType -> None},

  Initialization :> {f[u_, v_] := {u, v, (Cos[u] + Cos[v])/3};}]
```

[image: Manipulate]

Answer (score 5):

For the Arrows

```
f[u_, v_] := {u, v, (Cos[u] + Cos[v])/3};
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{f[u, v]}, {u, -4, 4}, {v, 0, 8},
         Axes -> False,  Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {8, 8, 1.5}, 
         PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]]], 
 Graphics3D@
  Table[{Red, PointSize[.025], Point@f[u, v], 
         Black, Arrow[{f[u, v], f[u, v] + D[f[t, v], t] /. t -> u}]}, 
  {u, -4, 4, 2}, {v, 0, 8, 2}]]
```

[image]

For getting the arrows in any direction a = { a1, a2 } instead of x, you may do:

```
Dot[{a1,a2}.#] & /@ D[f[u, v], {{u, v}}]
(*
-> {a1, a2, -(1/3) a1 Sin[u] - 1/3 a2 Sin[v]}
*)
```

**Edit**

Both derivatives and normal:

```
f[u_, v_] := {u, v, (Cos[u] + Cos[v])/3};
Show[
 Graphics3D@
  Table[{Red, PointSize[.025], Point@f[u, v], Black, Arrowheads[.02], 
    Arrow[{f[u, v], f[u, v] + D[f[t, v], t] /. t -> u}], 
    Arrow[{f[u, v], f[u, v] + D[f[u, t], t] /. t -> v}],
    Arrow[{f[u, v],  f[u, v] +
                     Cross[D[f[t, v], t] /. t -> u, 
                           D[f[u, t], t] /. t -> v]}]}, 
  {u, -4, 4, 2}, {v, 0, 8, 2}], 

 ParametricPlot3D[{f[u, v]}, {u, -4, 4}, {v, 0, 8}, 
     Axes -> False, Mesh -> 3, MeshStyle -> {{Opacity[0.1], LightBlue}}, 
     Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {8, 8, 1.5}, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: That completes the picture nicely.

Comment: You seem to have a knack for this. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the plot with points using  `Graphics3D[listofpoints]`, where `listofpoints` is a T*3 matrix list,  and the arrows using constructs like `Graphics3D[Arrow[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 0}, {3, 3, -1}, {4, 4, 0}}]]`. If they are all `Graphics3D` objects, you should be able to combine them with `Show`.

Sorry, I am not near a Mathematica installation to provide you with an example just now.

Comment: you mean something like Graphics3D[Point[{1, 1, 1}]] ?... because it's still not letting me combine them

Comment: @alice314159 - check that the code in your comment works on its own. If it does but they won't combine, then there is some deeper error I can't help you with until I am near a Mathematica installation.

Comment: it does work, although for some reason i can't manage to plot more than one point (then i get an error). I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: @alice I'll take a wild guess that the problem with more than one point is that you're using `Graphics[Point[one], Point[two], ...]` and need to enclose all the points in a list: `Graphics[{Point[one], Point[two], ...}]` or alternately using a "multi-point" `Graphics[Point[{one, two, ...}]]`.

Comment: @BrettChampion -  Or, rather, `Graphics3D[Point[{one, two, ...}]]`.

Comment: For some reason I have a horrible time remembering to type the '3D' on 'Graphics3D', but have no problems with 'Plot3D'...